# Android GPS get old location

Tags: android

I am coding GPS track app, i found a propplem that : some time it got my old position, and when I take battery out of phone and restart phone it work fine.
I don't know why, can you help me.?

Comment: Sample code? Using Google Play Services or the Location Provider?

Comment: I am using Location Provider

Comment: Code you have implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can retrieve location in Android. 
1. Using `LocationManager` 
2. Using `LocationClient` (Google play services)

1. Using `LocationManager`, you have to provide the `LocationManager` a `Provider` (GPS, NETWORK, WIFI, PASSIVE). In case of GPS provider, the `LocationManager` will use Hardware GPS to resolve the current location. If the **GPS is not available** at the moment and you call `GetLastKnownLocation()`. It will return you a `Location` Object from of the last location GPS has captured a location if there is any, and if there is not then it will return `null`. If you try `getTime()` method of `Location` Object you got from `getLastKnownLocation()` it will return you when the last location was captured. *Same thing goes for network, wifi or passive provider*.
2. Using `LocationClient` from google play services, the `LocationClient` will automatically give you the most accurate current `Location` using **ALL THREE (if available), GPS, WIFI, 3G (NETWORK) ** by calling `getLastLocation()`. Again this will return you a `Location` object and the rest of this will go as explained above.

Use any of this method which is more appropriate in your application.
**NOTE : LocationManager will require the device to have a hardware GPS and LocationClient will require Google play services, GPS is not a must, but if device has one then it will benefit the location to be more accurate**

Answer (score 0):

```
public final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Home.this.location=location;
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Home.this.location=null;
              }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }
          };

    public String gpsadd() {
        try {


        if(isGPS) {


                    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(Home.this, Locale.getDefault());
             try 
              {
                addflg=0;
                lat=location.getLatitude();
                lng=location.getLongitude();
                boolean lop=true;
                while(lop) {
                List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    lop=false;
                    addflg=1;
                    address = addresses.get(0);
                    s_addr=address.getAddressLine(0)+" "+address.getAddressLine(1)+" "+address.getAddressLine(2);
                    disp="Location\n "+address.getAddressLine(0)+"\n"+address.getAddressLine(1)+"\n"+address.getAddressLine(2);

                }

                }


              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
        } else {
            display("GPS not Enabled");

        }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return disp;
    }
```